# How to send bulk SMS messages with Twilio Java SDK?

Tags: java, twilio, sms, bulk

I've found plenty of information on how to send bulk of sms messages with Js, Python, PHP SDKs but nothing on **how to achieve this using Java**?

Here is a code snippet demonstrating the implementation for Python.

```
from twilio.rest import Client


account = "AC98e9a2817c2e0b4d38b42d1445ef42d9"
token = "your_auth_token"
client = Client(account, token)

notification = client.notify.services("ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")\
   .notifications.create(
    to_binding=[
        "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"+15555555555\"}",
        "{\"binding_type\":\"facebook-messenger\",\"address\":\"123456789123\"}"
    ],
    body="Hello Bob")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is an example of [sending bulk SMS messages with Java in the documentation for Twilio Notify](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource?code-sample=code-send-a-notification-to-bindings-in-the-request&code-language=Java&code-sdk-version=7.x).

Here is the example:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.notify.v1.service.Notification;

public class Example {
  // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "your_auth_token";

  public static final String SERVICE_SID = "ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Initialize the client
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    List<String> toBindings = Arrays.asList(
    "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"+15555555555\"}",
    "{\"binding_type\":\"facebook-messenger\",\"address\":\"123456789123\"}");

    Notification notification = Notification
        .creator(SERVICE_SID)
        .setBody("Hello Bob")
        .setToBinding(toBindings)
        .create();

    System.out.println(notification.getSid());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to take the opportunity and ask if there is a way to receive status callback updates for each SMS message in the bulk? Is it possible and if so can you please share a link to the documentation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the Messaging Service that you set up for Notify you can set up a Delivery Status Callback URL in the Integration settings and it will send you updates for each message sent through the service.

Comment: So each message will have an sid on status callback, but I wonder how can I get those after sending a batch so I can store it for further message identification on delivery status callback?

Comment: You can’t get that from the initial request. You do get other details in the callback that you could use to match it back, like the number you sent the message to. Could you use that?

Comment: Nope, there may be multiple records for the same number :(

Comment: You may want to send the messages with the regular message API then, rather than Notify. Then you can get the SID back in the response. You will just need to make one request to the API per message rather than sending in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official guide how to do that in java:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here. You can get started with free credits here which should last you a month or two if you’re using it for personal use. https://www.twilio.com/try-twilio

More details on working with your trial account here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-use-your-free-trial-account

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33603331)